# How can I create a sticky footer when I have a container div?

Tags: html, css

I have a working sticky footer with a page structured like this:

```
<body>
    <nav></nav>
    <main-content></main-content>
    <footer>
</body>
```

Because of a limitation of a JavaScript library I am using, I am forced to restructure my page like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="app-root">
        <nav></nav>
        <main-content></main-content>
        <footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

What is the simplest way to achieve the same sticky footer effect with the new parent element? I am able to use a different parent element as well, like an inline element, but that seemed like a hack and didnt give me the results I needed.

This did not work:

```
html, body, .app-root{
    height: 100vh;
}
```

This is the "sticky" behavior I am after:

[image]

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox is your friend. I HIGHLY recommend learning it.

```
.app-root {

  // You wouldnt actually need the height listed like this since your 
  // elems would have actual content.
  height: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;

  // Use flexbox for rendering content.
  display: flex;

  // This is telling the content to render vertically rather than
  // the native horizontal rendering.
  flex-direction: column;
}

main-content {

  // Tells this element to take up as much space as it can within
  // its parent.
  flex: auto;
}

nav {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

footer {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ezova0ty/

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 footer{
     position:fixed;
     bottom:0;
     left:0;
     right:0;
     height:<whatever size your footer needs>
 }
```

Hope i got you right in this

Comment: I cannot use fixed because I expect the footer to stick to the bottom of the main content. If the content is larger than the height of the page, the footer will be visible. If it is smaller, it will be stuck to the bottom of the view port. See the first image shown here: https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/

Comment: What i don't get... why do you want to scroll down the page more than necessary? 

Maybe you can set the app-root to 100% height? to do that, you need to make that one position:absolute